# WPF toolkit datagrid cell text wrapping

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell, word-wrap

My WPF datagrid's columns are fixed width, which means long text in the rows are cut off. How can I have the text wrap?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a DataGridTextColumn, you need to define the Style for the DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeLongText" Binding="{Binding MyText}">
  <dg:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    </Style>
  </dg:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</dg:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Full explination can be found at the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the cell with a Textblock with Textwrapping enabled.
i.e.

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" Width="*">
   <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>                                    
       </DataTemplate>
   </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DataGridTextColumn is being created in the code behind you can set the style and setters this way:

```
        _dataGridTextColumn.MaxWidth = 550;
        _dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(TextBlock));
        _dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
```

This will cause the text inside the _dataGridTextColumn to wrap as it would inside a TextBlock.